# How to move data from Oracle to Mysql Database using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, oracle

I need to move table data from Oracle db to Mysql db, using PHP.
However,it'll be an automated(JQUERY) process, that runs at 5 minute intervals.

Which is better to:

1) copy all table data from Oracle straight into Mysql, thus continously overwriting everything in Mysql?

2) or exporting data first to a CSV (or other external) file. 
Then using PHP to import it into Mysql?

I want to update the Mysql db with only the additional rows that were added into the Oracle db within the last 5 minutes. btw, PHP will be connecting to more than 5 Oracle dbs.

Which method has the least impact on RAM and PROCESSOR power, but still retains efficiency?

Comment: i had good experience with csv files. just look, that the structure of both database tables are the same!

Comment: Ok. thanks. That gives us two processes that must happen one after the other: 1) exporting from Oracle to CSV. And 2) Importing to Mysql.

Comment: so I understand correctly: you want to realize both processes with php or/and jquery?

Comment: yes! we are talking of huge data rows added into ORACLE almost every minute

Comment: Should I create a different CSV file after every 5 mins? Or do I append the existing CSV file with the latest rows added in Oracle in the last 5 minutes?

Comment: i would append. i think its faster when you just overwrite a file with the new data than create a new one with all of the data.

Comment: i maybe can help you with the terminated import of the csv files into mysql. but i never use oracle database in addition with php...

Comment: i found a simple JQUERY code that auto-refreshes at intervals. I will use that to query Oracle and dump a CSV file in C:drive. Then Mysql will upload that data(but only the rows that it does not have already)

Comment: Develope a code with PHP which export a CSV file from the ORACLE database to your C:drive. Then import this file to the mysql. similar content overwrites, the new one added. 
ask if you need help with your code. i will help you (when i can).
but my weekend starts in 15 Minutes, so i answer maybe at monday. :)

Comment: Thanks mate! Unfortunately, i cant overwrite the data once it's imported into Mysql. That's because it is immediately assigned to several users for further processing and generation of reports. Once i overwrite it, it means the users have to start processing afresh again. I only need to import into Mysql, the latest rows in the CSV file. New rows must be be added, but similar rows must be ignored.

Comment: Lets say you want to load the result in the table "a" 
1. Load the new csv into a temp table (b) 
2. Do a left outer join on b and a. (When we do a join, we will get all the elements in a and b.
When we do left outer join, we will get elements in b, but not in a. This is what we want).<br />
3. Result from step 2, can be inserted in a. Use the same query or a temp table.

- Sophia Life
i think this query works pretty well for my test tables...

Comment: urks, sorry for the layout, can't insert html...

Comment: @dTDesign Thanks a bunch! I think you just cracked the final piece of the puzzle.

Comment: To everyone, Thanks for your time and precious tips. You guys are the best. Let me now delve into the code right away.